# Multiple micro service or console application that read from a single table

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, microservices

I need to read millions of records from a sqlserver table through a microservice that does block reads in parallel. each instantiated microservice performs the same read operation on the same table of the same DB. what is the best approach you can use to avoid taking duplicate records?
By duplicate records I mean not to process / collect records that have already been collected / processed by other instances of the same service

Can I use this approach? make selections from each microservice such as the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT ITEM_ID
FROM TABLE_ITEM
WITH(XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE ITEM_PRIORITY > 10 AND ITEM_CATEGORY = 'CT1' AND ITEM_STATUS = 'available' AND ROWNUM = 1;
UPDATE [locked item_id] SET ITEM_STATUS = 'unavailable';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: "Taking duplicate records" - what does it mean? Duplicate in what sense, around which data? Is your table some kind of "queue" on steroids? Why is your reads block, can you do uncommited reads? I think you first need to read about CAP theorem before touching microservice paradigm - https://hub.packtpub.com/the-cap-theorem-in-practice-the-consistency-vs-availability-trade-off-in-distributed-databases/#:~:text=Consistency%20%E2%80%93%20that%20reads%20are%20always,a%20response%20(when%20valid).

Comment: I have millions of records to process, the idea is to use a microservice that does this by having the ability to scale horizontally (so start multiple instances of the same microservice) to speed up operations but not risk processing the same records

Comment: So in other words, your records represent a "task" with "state". Which implies you need a queue, which implies you need producer microservice (just one, for your db) which will fill this queue with those tasks (or duplicates in case of fails), and your consumers will process them one by one. And all you need is to check state validity in your consumers (id processed or not, you can cache it). Just put your data in kafka (or any other message-bus), then scale processing.

Comment: due to cost and time issues we cannot use products like kafka but I would like to approach a function that does what I need even in a rudimentary way

Comment: make an abstraction above other SQL table - it doesn't matter which message-bus you use, it just need to be persistent. Even file will do. Later you can switch to production ready solutions:  kafka, eventhub, rabbitmq, etc. You just need to get away from "pulling" your tasks to "push" your tasks.

Comment: How frequently is the `SELECT` command invoked by each microservice/console app?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think it doesnt matter because it will be scaled with number of microservices (he wants to scale processing/consuming) - sqlserver will be a bottleneck and microservices will DDOS database table with millions of records with a complex filtering query for state instead lookup by id.

Comment: @eocron the SQL Server is a robust piece of software. It has been optimized for decades, and offers plenty of options for manual optimization. I wouldn't ditch it based sorely on principles, before getting a grasp of the magnitude/scale of the project.